# Highlight entire row in Django admin list

Tags: javascript, python, css, django

I've been stuck on this issue for days. I have a change_list with applicants, now I want to highlight the rows of objects that have been changed recently.

To do this I made a custom property:

```
@property
def has_recently_been_modified(self):
    return datetime.now() - self.updated_at < timedelta(days=5)
```

Which I use in the admin.py to create a field that houses a class I need:

```
 def recently_modified(self, obj):
    if obj.has_recently_been_modified:
        return mark_safe("<span class='row_yellow'></span>")

recently_modified.allow_tags = True
list_display = ('custom_status','viewed', 'updated_at', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'vacancy', 'created_at', 'recently_modified')
```

And with JS I use that class to color the row:

```
window.onload = function () {
        const x = document.getElementsByClassName("row_yellow");
        let i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            let ligne = x[i].parentNode;
            while (ligne.tagName !== "TR") {
                ligne = ligne.parentNode;
            }
            ligne.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        }
    }
```

Although it does color the entire row, the extra empty column at the end of the row is a real thorn in my eye. Removing it from the list_display doesn't obviously work.

**So my question is, is there a clever way to "hide" it? Or even a completely different method to color the row?**

I have tried using *django-liststyle*, but that seems like a broken package. I immediatly get a TemplateSyntaxError at the second import line in their file.